# Why does bluetooth turns itself off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, bluetooth, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have a Galaxy S4 (GT-9505) here where Bluetooth is turning itself off. Sometimes this happens after a few seconds. Other times it takes longer or even stays on. Also, if it stays on can't find other devices with turned-on visibility.

Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/MP3YyQxS I cut a lot of unrelated stuff out and it starts right before I activate Bluetooth and ends right after it deactivates itself

Does anybody have similar experience?

Comment: Seems like the system tries to read a non-existing file. Try to delete application data of the *Bluetooth* app (package name: `com.android.bluetooth`)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Battery Saving Mode is ON.   By turning that function off on my phone, the Bluetooth issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I had this same issue, but with Bluetooth and WiFi; Turns out to be the Bluetooth & Wifi Card on the phone, it had been damaged... How? After letting my phone fall too much times.

That phone wasn't able to operate anymore, because the only solution was to brass the card to the motherboard again and it would work normally, but there was a risk of damaging other parts of the motherboard when doing this process. Finally I tried it and didn't work, so I also damaged the mb and the phone died.

I RECOMMEND CHECKING YOUR PHONE WITH AN EXPERT